# Adding new (key,value) pair in nested dictionary - python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

Hi there I created a (what I call) nested dictionary:

```
gradeDict = { 
   "Intro to Programming":{ 
      "student":{ 
         "firstname":"Mike",
         "lastname":"Miller",
         "marks":{ 
            "PS01":70,
            "PS02":80
         }
      }
   }
}
print(gradeDict['Intro to Programming']['student']['marks'])
```

which after asking for the values in key 'marks' gives the values

```
{'PS01': 70, 'PS02': 80}
```

That's perfect. Now I want add a NEW (key,value) pair to the superior key 'marks':

```
gradeDict.update( {"Intro to Programming":{ "student":{ "firstname":"Mike",
         "lastname":"Miller","marks":{ "PS03":10}}}} )

print(gradeDict['Intro to Programming']['student']['marks'])
```

Unfortunately this gives

```
{'PS03': 10}
```

which I don't understand, a key should only be overwritten if it already exists, otherwise appended. 'marks' exists, but 'PS03' doesn't. What am I missing here, or how to get the desired entry:

```
{'PS01': 70, 'PS02': 80, 'PS03': 10}
```

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good reasoning, but `dict.update` doesn't exactly work like that. It doesn't recursively check each element, instead it sees that the key `"Intro to Programming"` already exists in the first layer so it overwrites its value with `{"student":{ "firstname":"Mike", "lastname":"Miller","marks":{ "PS03":10}}}`.

See this demonstration:

```
gradeDict = { 
   "Intro to Programming":{ 
      "student":{ 
         "firstname":"Mike",
         "lastname":"Miller",
         "marks":{ 
            "PS01":70,
            "PS02":80
         }
      }
   }
}

gradeDict.update(
    {"Intro to Programming": {"NEW VALUE": {"firstname": "Mike", "lastname": "Miller","marks": {"PS03": 10}}}}
)

print(gradeDict)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {'Intro to Programming': {'NEW VALUE': {'firstname': 'Mike', 'lastname': 'Miller', 'marks': {'PS03': 10}}}}
> ```

---

If you want that kind of recursive updating, a quick Google search [found for example this](https://gist.github.com/angstwad/bf22d1822c38a92ec0a9) (adapted to work with Python 3, not tested extensively):

```
from collections.abc import Mapping


def dict_merge(dct, merge_dct):
    for k, v in merge_dct.items():
        if (k in dct and isinstance(dct[k], dict)
                and isinstance(merge_dct[k], Mapping)):
            dict_merge(dct[k], merge_dct[k])
        else:
            dct[k] = merge_dct[k]


gradeDict = { 
   "Intro to Programming":{ 
      "student":{ 
         "firstname":"Mike",
         "lastname":"Miller",
         "marks":{ 
            "PS01":70,
            "PS02":80
         }
      }
   }
}

dict_merge(gradeDict, {"Intro to Programming": {"student": {"firstname": "Mike", "lastname": "Miller","marks": {"PS03": 10}}}})

print(gradeDict)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {'Intro to Programming': {'student': {'firstname': 'Mike', 'lastname': 'Miller', 'marks': {'PS01': 70, 'PS02': 80, 'PS03': 10}}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will work fine, but is way more non-pythonic than I thought! I felt that recursive updating should be a main feature of dictionaries (in general).